# error on azure table storage upload file using nodejs expreesjs

Tags: node.js, azure, express, ecmascript-6, azure-blob-storage

> I m trying to upload images/videos file on to azure blob storage using
> nodejs. But on uploading through postman Im getting error, even though
> I can see the file object in console. Below is the code for it.

```
const addProductImage = async (req: any, res: Response) => {
    try {
        console.log(req.files.file);

        if (!req.files) {
            res.status(400).send({ status: Status.ERROR, error: "No file uploaded" });
        }

        let file = req.files.file;
        const sharedKeyCred = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accName, acckey)
        const blobServClient1 = new BlobServiceClient(`https://${accName}.blob.core.windows.net`, sharedKeyCred)
        const containerClient1 = blobServClient1.getContainerClient(containerName)
        const blockBlobClient = containerClient1.getBlockBlobClient(file.name);
        await blockBlobClient.upload(file, file.size);

        res.status(200).send({ status: Status.SUCCESS, });
    }
    catch (error: any) {
        res.status(500).send({ status: Status.ERROR, error });
    }
}
```

> the above codes console is -

```
{
  name: 'hclTech.png',
  data: <Buffer 81 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52 00 00 02 7u 00 00 00 75 08 06 00 00 00 3f 4a 88 b4 00 00 00 01 73 52 47 42 00 ae ce 1c e9 00 00 00 07 ... 54120 more bytes>,
  size: 54170,
  encoding: '7bit',
  tempFilePath: '',
  truncated: false,
  mimetype: 'image/png',
  md5: 'd64ae80f1625e3c766b67bcf05a152a8',
  mv: [Function: mv]
}
```

> On uploading a file in postman under form-data with "file" as key and
> hitting post, it gives error

Comment: Could you include what error you are getting while hitting post?

Comment: @Sridevi it's 500 status error from catch

Answer (score 0):

- Here If you use `multer` [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) to read the file in the form-data.
- Then you can set Multer to read the form-data where the file is using the `.single('<Name of the Feild>')` . Here the name of the field must be the same one in which you are adding the file. here I am using the postman with field name as `test`

[image]

- Now you can set up multer like this

```
var  multer = require('multer');
var  upload = multer();
app.use(upload.single('test'));
```

Complete Api code :

```
var  express = require('express');
var  multer = require('multer');
const { BlobServiceClient } = require("@azure/storage-blob");

  

var  app = express();
var  upload = multer();

  

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended:  false }));
app.use(upload.single('test'));

  

const  blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString('<Connection String From Portal>');

const  containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient('< Name of the Container>');

app.get('/', async (req,res)=>{
    const  blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(req.file.originalname.toString());
    await  blockBlobClient.upload(file.toString() , file.size);
    res.send(req.file.size.toString());
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Postman output:

[image]

Portal:

[image]

Comment: Can you add the images completely , as I can just see the alt

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/cUpoNxw.png - I can see the Images. Could you check the internet connection and refresh the browser.